# Add serial column to a partitioned table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, table-partitioning

We have a table which is partitioned, we now want to add a `serial id column` to the table.

Do we need to `explicitly` add the id column to all the portioned tables or we just need to add the column to the `master` table.

Any help in this would be really great.

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `serial` is discouraged in favor of the standard compliant `identity` columns.

Comment: Just the master table. You can test this yourself and you have to test anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an existing regular table become a partition of a partitioned table. Then There is only one physical table.

> The partitioned table itself is a “**virtual**” table having no storage of
> its own. Instead, the storage belongs to partitions, which are
> otherwise-ordinary tables associated with the partitioned table. Each
> partition stores a subset of the data as defined by its partition
> bounds. All rows inserted into a partitioned table will be routed to
> the appropriate one of the partitions based on the values of the
> partition key column(s). Updating the partition key of a row will
> cause it to be moved into a different partition if it no longer
> satisfies the partition bounds of its original partition.
>
> Partitions may themselves be defined as partitioned tables, resulting
> in sub-partitioning. **Although all partitions must have the same
> columns as their partitioned parent, partitions may have their own
> indexes, constraints and default values, distinct from those of other
> partitions.** See CREATE TABLE for more details on creating partitioned
> tables and partitions.

```
begin;
 CREATE temp TABLE list_parted (
     a int primary key ,
     b text
) PARTITION BY range (a);
CREATE temp TABLE l_part (a int primary key, b text );
CREATE temp TABLE l_part_2 (a int primary key, b text );
insert into l_part values (1),(2);
ALTER TABLE list_parted ATTACH PARTITION l_part FOR VALUES FROM (1) TO (10);
ALTER TABLE list_parted ATTACH PARTITION l_part_2 FOR VALUES FROM (11) TO (19);
commit ;



alter table list_parted  add column test_serial bigserial;
\d l_part_2
```

return

```
                                    Table "pg_temp_3.l_part_2"
+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
|   Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                     Default                      |
+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| a           | integer |           | not null |                                                  |
| b           | text    |           |          |                                                  |
| test_serial | integer |           | not null | nextval('list_parted_test_serial_seq'::regclass) |
+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
Partition of: list_parted FOR VALUES FROM (11) TO (19)
Indexes:
    "l_part_2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (a)
```

However:

```
alter table list_parted  add column test_serial1 integer generated always as identity;
```

then error occurs:

```
--ERROR:  cannot recursively add identity column to table that has child tables
```

Comment: Hi Mark, are you suggesting that adding a serial column is possible and we should add it to only the Master table but adding a `identity` column to the master table is not possible?

Comment: for serial, you need need to add to the main table. Since there is only one physical table. to add another column data type identify, for now I don't know how to do that.